# Is there any proof not depending tenseor product?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modules, representation-theory, tensor-products

**Theorem:** Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$ with $\dim(V)<\infty$ and assume that  $V$ is irreducible and faithful $FG$ module where $G$ is a group of order $m$. Then $Z(G)$ is cyclic.

In the proof of this theorem, if $F$ contains a primitive $m$ roots of unity $w$, then it is easy to show this.(it can be shown by $Z(G)$ acts on $V$ by scalers)

In general case, Set $W=V\otimes_FL$ where $L=F(w)$. Then $W$ is also a $G$ module. By studying on irreducible submodule $U$ of $W$, proof can be completed.

This proof is very nice but I wonder that is there any proof not depending on the tensor product?

Comment: Schur's lemma says that the centralizing algebra of the image of an irreducible representation is a division ring $D$. Then $Z(G)$ is in the centre of $D$, which is a field, and any finite multiplicative subgroup of a field is cyclic.

Comment: Do you mean the following? $Hom_G(V,V)$ is a division ring as $V$ is irrdeducable. Since $Z(G)$ comutes with element of $G$, $Z(G)$ can be embedded into $Hom_G(V,V)$. For $\phi\in Hom_G(V,V)$, $\phi g(v)=g\phi v$. Thus, $Z(G)$ contained in the center of $Hom_G(V,V)$ and the result follows.

Comment: Yes that's right. You can think of ${\rm Hom}_G(V,V)$ as the set of matrices that commute with all of the matrices in the image of the representation affording $V$. Then it is clear that this contains $Z(G)$.

Comment: Let me ask you one more question. Center of the division ring $D$  clearly contains the filed $F$. Is it possible that $F$ is proper in $Z(D)$?

Comment: Yes certainly. This is true for all reducible but not absolutely reducible representations over finite fields, because finite division rings are fields. But it can happen in characteristic $0$ too. For example, for the $2$-dimensional irreducible represenation of $C_3$ over ${\mathbb R}$, $D \cong {\mathbb C}$.